# How to get defaultValue property value of dialog in AEM

Tags: javascript, aem

I've a dialog selection box. What I need to check if the default value I've provided using  the property defaultValue and value I'll get from the selection box are equal or not!

So, to get selected value, we can get like this :

```
function(dialog){ 
var selection = dialog.getField("<property name>"); 
var selectedValue = selection.value;
}
```

Now, how can I get value in javascript using the **defaultValue** property as name?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation for the [ExtJS *Selection* widget](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.form.Selection), you should be able to access the `defaultValue` as a simple property.

This quick and dirty test seems to confirm it. It outputs `dog` whenever I select a value. Take a look at the `selectionchanged` listener to see how the value is accessed (and please never put a `console.log` in a listener like I did, that was just the quickest way for me to run it and see it ;D )

```
<animal
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    allowBlank="true"
    defaultValue="dog"
    fieldLabel="Animal"
    name="./animal"
    type="select"
    xtype="selection">
    <options jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
        <dog
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            text="Dog"
            value="dog"/>
        <cat
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            text="Cat"
            value="cat"/>
        <mouse
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            text="Mouse"
            value="mouse"/>
    </options>
    <listeners
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        selectionchanged="function(selection, value) {console.log(selection.defaultValue)}"
    </listeners>
</animal>
```

To tackle your example specifically, you're using `dialog.getField("name");` to obtain the field.

[`Dialog#getField`](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.Dialog) returns a `Field` or `Field[]` (array of fields) object depending on the number of fields matched by the name.

A [`CQ.ext.form.Field`](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.Ext.form.Field) on the other hand, should also have a `defaultValue` present.

If you can't just access `selection.defaultValue` in the code you posted, I guess that either `selection` is actually an array that you have to iterate over, or that something is wrong with the configuration of your dialog (check the `dialog.xml` and make sure `defaultValue` is actually there at the right level.